# jQuery tab order kills drag/drop/sort lists

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable, droppable

I am stuck in a problem with jQuery. I try to make a list from elements, that can be dragged and dropped in many lists. But this whole thing is inside a tab. Here is it shown as it supposed to work:

http://redbird.lv/problem/jquery_doeswork.html

The interesting thing starts if I try to change the order of tabs. If the tab is not the first opened, than it's not working until there is a element in the lists you can drop in and move it (awake?). Here is my problem example:

As I cannot post more than 1 link, this not working link is VERY visible in the working example.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? I think, the sortables must be .('refresh'); on tab open, but

```
$('#tabcontainer').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
$('.sortable_boxes').sortable('refresh');
});
```

is not doing the job. So I am out of guesses. Will appreciate any help!
Thanks!
Edgars

Answer (score 2):

Found solution by myself:

```
$('#all_boxes > li').bind('dragstart', function(event, ui) { $
('.sortable_boxes').sortable('refresh'); });
```

Maybe this can be helpful for someone who has similar problem.